# Android WebView - catch link if has javascript embedded

Tags: android, webview

In my android app I have a WebView loading a webpage. This webpage was built by someone else and each html href does a javascript _*dopostback() to get the URL to navigate to. For example: href="javascript:*_dopostback(function(params))".

My goal is to check to see if a link clicked from the WebView does have the javascript __dopostback() event in the html href.

I used onTouch() and created a toast that shows me the URL when something is clicked but it is giving me the URL created after the __dopostback() event. I want the actual __dopostback() reference. For example: in my toast it would say __dopostback(function(params) rather than the URL it creates. Exactly as it does when I mouseover a link on the web page outside of the android browser.

I also tried using the HitTestResult.getType() == 0 because I heard that android treats all javascript buttons as UNKNOWN. This works to activate the toast but I can't figure out how to display the javascript:__dopostback(function(params)) in the toast simliar to mousing over the link on a webpage when using a standard browser on my pc.